# Click event on HTML5 / CakePHP form not working

Tags: jquery, html, cakephp

This is basically the form in cake:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($container, ['class' => 'form-horizontal', 'autocomplete' => 'off']) ?>  
// some inputs
<?= $this->Form->control('user_text', ['label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-info w-75 btn-save-cnl']) ?> <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw align-middle invisible"></i>  
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

and currently the jquery file:

```
$(function() {
  $('.btn-save-cnl').bind('click', function(event) {
    /* Act on the event */
   $(this).prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

the textarea "user_text" is validated via html5 with the required attr.
I want to prevent double click when submitting the form.
I already tried novalidate form and bind/on/click event, also adding id/name to form/button but got nothing.

Using cakePHP 3.5.3, Jquery 3.2.1 and Bootstrap 4

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. You've forget to add te **jQuery CDN**
2. Also forget to `fetch` your script using the :

   `$this->start("scriptBottom");
   $this->end();
   echo $this->fetch('scriptBottom');`

This is a full working code:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($container, ['class' => 'form-horizontal', 'autocomplete' => 'off']) ?>
    // some inputs
<?= $this->Form->control('user_text', ['label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-info w-75 btn-save-cnl']) ?> <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw align-middle invisible"></i>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>

<?php
$this->Html->script([
    'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'
],
    ['block' => 'script']);

$this->start("scriptBottom");
?>
<script>
$(function() {
$('.btn-save-cnl').bind('click', function(event) {
/* Act on the event */
alert("CLICKED");
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
});
</script>

<?php
$this->end();
echo $this->fetch('scriptBottom');
?>
```

Comment: I do have the jquery library in the layout.  And for some reason I stop xampp and try again, but now the code works.

Comment: If the jQuery was included in the layout, this answer does not have any effect.

Comment: @DanielW how about fetching the script ?! you know that if you're script is not fetched then it will not run ?!

Comment: @MehdiBouzidi The fetching would make sense if it would be placed in the layout, so that would ensure that all scripts would be rendered after the content. But in your solution the fetch would render the script exactly the same place as it would without the fetch. The javascript would also run without the fetch.

Comment: @DanielW how can you explain that my code solved the issue ?!

Comment: @DanielW huum Okey, so you think that it's better if I delete my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

By default the button does not submit the form, try to add type=>submit to the button:

```
<?= $this->Form->button('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-info w-75 btn-save-cnl', 'type' => 'submit']) ?>
```

Comment: Cake generates that when it renders the page.  
`<button class="btn btn-info w-75 btn-save-cnl" type="submit" disabled="">Save</button>`. For some reason I stop xampp and try again with your answer, but now the code works.